# Java- Linking .png images with integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code that first shuffles an Array of 5 elements (1,2,3,4,5).  My second for loop compares a userInput to the elements in the Array and if there is a match (user inputs 3 and there is a 3 in the Array) then the program switches the user input to index 0 and whatever was in index 0 to the previous position of the user index.

I have five .png images of cards (Ace, Two, Three, Four,Five).  I want my program to display these images instead of an Array of integers.  Also I want the images to switch places when the user clicks on one.  How can I change my for loop so the images of cards are changing locations instead of just the numbers in an Array?

```
int place = 0
int[] deck = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
    int j = 1+Math.random()*5
    place = deck[i];
    deck[i]= deck[j];
    deck[j]=place;
}

for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
    if(userInput == deck[i]) {
        place = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[0];
        deck[0] = place
        return deck;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deck));
```

Comment: @ScottHunter How do I link the images to each number?  For example the Ace.png would be represented by the integer 1 in the Array. And when I click on an image it should move according to the rules of my second for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not enough details to really answer, for instance is this a CLI app (command line app), web-based app, Swing/AWT app?  If it's web-based, are you using something like Spring or something else?  Without these details, it's hard to say what exactly you would do to display images, but I will try to help in as generic a way as possible...

**CLI App** - CLI you are screwed.  Java CLI apps do not have any means to display an image as CLI is text-based.  There may be some crazy libraries that support images, but for the most part I don't think there is a direct way to do this in a CLI app.  One work-around would be to print ASCII representations of your cards.  Then you "images" would be text-based and can be easily printed with `System.println()`.  You can find such ASCII pictures all over the web.

**Web App** - Web-based app is easy, for the most part, but the complication is in how you want to approach it.  For instance you could have an API rest call that returns the right PNG image based on the URL string, or your could pass the Index.  Or you could use JSPs to render the page with the right image based on the index.  Again, the complication here is that there are WAY too many ways to do the same thing, they all have pluses/minuses, and they all depend on what frameworks you are using.  The cool part here is that the browser can do the work of handling the PNG display.

**Swing/AWT** - It has literally be AGES since I wrote a Swing/AWT-based app, but if memory serves I believe you would want to use a JPanel for Swing and maybe a Canvas for AWT?  Someone else more comfortable in Swing/AWT would have to comment to be sure.

As far as how to connect the images to your index, again there are several ways you could do this.  You could create a wrapper class that has the index and the image (either the path or the fully loaded image object) and use the same list you have now, OR you could use something like a `Map` which has a key/value, where you key could be the index and the value could be the image (again, path or other).  You could even create a specialized `List` of your own by implementing the java.util.List interface that uses an internal `List` of index numbers and a `Map` to relate the index to the images.

The problem with using a `Map` alone is that typically `Map`s and `Set`s don't maintain order, meaning if you try to get them back out in a specific order you can't.  However, there are implementations of `Map` that do maintain order, namely `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap`.  `LinkedHashMap` maintains the insertion order of the keys and `TreeMap` uses either `Comparator` or if the objects within are `Comparable` to set the order of the keys.

There are probably other ways to do this as well.  It really depends on what you are comfortable with and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: To be honest, I haven’t been coding long enough to know the differences between these apps.  I have been learning Java logic for a while and now I want to branch off to making interfaces and interactive things but I’m not sure where to start.

Comment: TBH I would start with a web app using Spring Boot.  It will get you started faster and give you more "real world" experience, like the type that could get you a job if you wanted.